# JS: Understanding difference between class prototypes and function constructor prototypes

Tags: javascript

First, if I have base class:

```
class User {
    constructor(username) {
        this.username = username
    }

    logUser() {
       return this.username;
    }
}
```

then extend a class:

```
class Admin extends User {
    constructor(username) {
        super(username)
    }

    otherStuff() {
       return "I am an admin";
    }
}

let user = new User("coolGuy");

let admin = new Admin("adminGuy");
```

if I check admin's prototype, I have:

```
__proto__: User
     ->constructor: class Admin
     ->otherStuff: ƒ otherStuff()
     ->__proto__: Object
         -->constructor: class User
         -->logUser: ƒ logUser()
         -->__proto__: Object
```

so although `otherStuff()` is defined directly within the `Admin` class, it's in the created `admin` object's prototype and everything the `Admin` class inherited from `User` is within the next level of that prototype chain, right?

Does this differ from function constructors in that if I define a function within a constructor, it is part of the object and not part of the prototype.  Like as follows:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
 
    this.getName() {
         return "My name is " + this.name;
    }
}

let john = new Person('john');
```

If I look at `john`, `name` and `getName()` are both directly on it and not nested in the prototype.  The constructor is in the prototype but `getName()` is now directly on the newly created `john` but when using classes, `otherStuff()` was *not* directly on the newly created `admin`.
Is that a fair difference to say that exists between the two?

Answer (score 0):

> it's in the created admin object's prototype and everything the Admin class inherited from User is within the next level of that prototype chain, right?

Yep - to be a bit more precise, the prototype chain here would be:

```
instance <- Admin.prototype <- User.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

Anything that exists on `Admin.prototype` or `User.prototype` (or `Object.prototype`) will be visible to the `instance` via direct property lookup.

> Does this differ from function constructors in that if I define a function within a constructor, it is part of the object and not part of the prototype.

With that code, the only difference is that all the properties you care about are directly on the instance. The prototype chain for `john` is:

```
john (the instance) <- Person.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

But `Person.prototype` is basically an empty object; both the properties you care about on `john`, the `name` and `getName`, are directly on the instance.

If you wanted to put the `getName` onto the `Person` using a function instead of a class, you could do:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
    return "My name is " + this.name;
}
```

This would be pretty similar to how `otherStuff` exists on an Admin instance, or how `logUser` exists on a User instance - they both exist on the internal prototype one level above the instance.